# Process parallel multiple read in spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have one file which contains some record and i have second file which also contains same record but with more details , so i want to process in a way that read one record from first file and search in second. 
How to read two files in parallel ?

Update :

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(readFilefromDirectory(), fileInboundPollingConsumer())
                    .split(fileSplitter())
                .channel(c ->c.executor(id, executor))
```

here in first line we are reading first file and then splitting it sending to executer channel so i want to know where should i write logic to read second file means to read from directory and then search record in that excel file .

Answer (score 1):

All the parallel work in Spring Integration can be done via `ExecutorChannel`.

I'd suggest to use `FileSplitter` for the first file and an `ExecutorChannel` as an output.

As for the second file... Well, I'd read it once into the memory e.g. as a `Map` if you have some delimiter between `record` and its `details`. And use that memory store for incoming record.

**UPDATE**

If the second file is very big, you can do like this:

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file);
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = scanner.nextLine();
     if(line.startsWith(payload)) {
        return line;
      }
 }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(readFilefromDirectory(), fileInboundPollingConsumer())
            .split(fileSplitter())
            .channel(c ->c.executor(id, executor))
            .handle("searchService", "searchMethod")
```

where `searchService` is some service `@Bean` (or just `@Service`) and `searchMethod` utilize logic to accept the `String line` and implement logic to do the search in other file. That search operation will be done in parallel for each splitted like.

The logic to read Excel file is out of Spring Integration scope. That is fully different question.

Comment: But if second file is big means (2 million records) will it be good to put in memory ?

Comment: Where should i write logic to read second file in executer channel ?

Comment: ??? I the Service Activator: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#service-activator. That must custom Java code to accept a line as a result of the `FileSplitter`.

Comment: See an UPDATE2 in my answer.

Comment: But second file may be any thing (txt or excel) is also in same directory where first file is but with different name ,My question is where should i write logic to read second file from directory ? If i write after executer channel then it will repeated read to file .

Comment: It will repeat, of course. Because you don't want to read it fully to the memory and you can't get access to the same FileInputStream in memory from different threads. You can pick up the second file to the header (`.enrichHeaders()`) just after `readFilefromDirectory()` and before `.split()`. And use it from the downstream service-activator.